# Use Html.BeginForm can not find action name in control (asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my control

[image]

/ProductController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ShoppingStore.Domain.Abstract;
using ShoppingStore.Domain.Entities;
using ShoppingStore.WebUI.Models;

namespace ShoppingStore.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private IProductsRepository repository; 

        public int PageSize = 4;

        public ProductController(IProductsRepository productRepository)
        {
            this.repository = productRepository;
        }


        public ViewResult List(string category , int page=1)
        {
            ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel
            {
                // Products = repository.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductID).Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize),
                Products = repository.Products.Where(p => category ==null || p.Category ==category).OrderBy(p => p.ProductID).Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize),
                PageInfo = new PagingInfo {CurentPage = page,ItemPerPage = PageSize,TotalItems = category == null ? repository.Products.Count() : repository.Products.Where(e => e.Category == category).Count()},
                CurrentCategory = category
            };
     
            return View(model);
        }  
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(List<string> hiddenList)
        {
            return View();
        } 

    }
}
```

[image]

This is View

/Views/Product/List.cshtml

```
@model ShoppingStore.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Prodcuts";
 
}

<script src="~/Scripts/pop_window.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/tool.js"></script>

@foreach (var p in Model.Products)
{
 @Html.Partial("ProductSummary",p)
}
<div>
    @Html.PageLinks(Model.PageInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new { page = x , category = Model.CurrentCategory}))
</div>
<div>
 
    <div id="result" style="display:none;"></div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
            <ol id="test"></ol>
            <div id="detail">
                <div>
                    <input class="ice-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="driink_d" id="BigICE" value="BigICE">cold/big/L $8<br>
                    <input class="ice-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="driink_d" id="MidHOT" value="MidHOT">hot/mid/M $7<br>
                    <input class="ice-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="driink_d" id="BigHOT" value="BigHOT">hot/big/L $7<br>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="size-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="driink_d" id="NOICE" value="NOICE">no ice<br>
                    <input class="size-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="driink_d" id="NORL" value="NORL">normal<br>
                    <input class="size-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="driink_d" id="LESSICE" value="LESSICE">less ice<br>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="sugar-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="driink_d" id="LESS" value="LESS">Less<br>
                    <input class="sugar-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="driink_d" id="HALF" value="HALF">half<br>
                    <input class="sugar-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="driink_d" id="FULL" value="FULL">full<br>
                    <input class="sugar-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="driink_d" id="NOS" value="NOS">no<br>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div id='DIV2'><input type="button" onclick="incrementValue1()" value="ADD" /></div>
                <div id="DIV2"> <input type="text" id="number1" value="0" /></div>
                <div id="DIV2"><input type="button" onclick="decrementValue1()" value="minus" /></div>
            </div>


            <button id="checkvalue" onclick="checkValue()" type="submit">Check</button>

        </div>
 
    }
```

When my project starts running, List.cshtml work is fine .

It can read data from the database, and show information to browser.

But I have a form, want to send some values to ProductController.cs .

It can not work, even I put breakpoint in ProductController.cs .

use `Html.BeginForm("Save", "Product", FormMethod.Post)`

It can not find 'Save' action name in the ProductController.cs

Comment: You method is not marked with `[HttpPost]` - but you have other errors and the value of your `hiddenList` will be `null`.

Comment: i add [HttpPost] , it do not work . then i correct my post information.thank your relpy.

Comment: Are you getting an error message to know it isn't finding the Save action?  Or how do you know the core issue is that it can't find the Save action?

Answer (score 2):

You should change your method signature with below :

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Save(ProductsListViewModel modelData)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Now check and let me know !!

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and it works fine on my machine. I noticed that you will trigger a Javascript function when submitting your form, this maybe where causes the problem. Press `F12` in browse to turn on developer tools and check if there is any error shows in the console.

Or if it showed an error page, it would be very helpful if you could shows more details of the error to let us help you.

Besides, there are several parts you need to change to pass form values to controller successfully:

1. Html attribute `id` is used to reference to the element itself so it should be unique. If there are multiple elements have the same `id` in the same page, only the first one will be found when you use `id` to access it in Javascript.
2. Html attribute `name` is used to reference the value of
   elements when a form is submitted, and .NET MVC uses it to bind
   values with a controller's parameters. Make sure the `name` you gave matches the name of controller's parameters.

   ```
    <div id="DIV2"> <input type="text" name="number1" value="0" /></div>
   ```

   And your controller should look like this:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Save(List<string> driink_d, int number1)
   {
       // Do something here
   }
   ```

If it showed an error page, it would be very helpful to include details of the error.